# Type narrowing for Partial doesn't seem to work

Tags: typescript

I have a fairly simple class named `Animal`. It can take, as a constructor argument, a plain object with matching property names/types:

```js
class Animal {
  kingdom:string;
  species:string;

  constructor(config?:Partial<Animal>) {
    this.kingdom = config?.kingdom ?? "";
    this.species = config?.species ?? "";
  }
}
```

Nothing too complicated so far.

But then later I have an array of animals. My function to add animals to the array will accept either an instance of Animal or an Animal config object, like so:

```js
const animals:Animal[] = [];
function addAnimal(animal:Animal|Partial<Animal>) {
  if (!(animal instanceof Animal)) animal = new Animal(animal);
  animals.push(animal);
}
```

This code absolutely ensures that the `animal` variable will refer to an instance of `Animal`, but I get the following compiler error:

```
Argument of type 'Animal | Partial<Animal>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Animal'.
  Type 'Partial<Animal>' is not assignable to type 'Animal'.
    Types of property 'kingdom' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

(See the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBYAUNaA1ovAOYAmA9sgFwQAuATsSQNy74QAOApsItxFqNmbHO2jAK8egwCuwOhQYAKSfABmiEgH5qABTAM6iNAB4EKNAD4AlJnH46AC0QQAdEVKVk0ALwSpTR0PZm9obW1oACIo0XxHF3cuXn4YfzUg7TdkvgFwyJi46ABfXFKxHDV6aDAkVBBBC3qAbQBdP2g20XVZeAVEKRqyMia0ZVrLEGpRkAAfAyMTEHM66ztsPGhEdWhlAEJx1fRielrgbgodmZs7CfqO+G4Adzgjw8mbIru0d05ZCCc73qnzKQA) for additional details)

I understand that `Animal` and `Partial<Animal>` are very similar, but I had hoped that the explicit assigned would narrow my `animal` variable to `Animal`. The code itself is perfectly fine, so this is really just a struggle with TypeScript.

I've tried a couple different (less than savory) workarounds, including:

1. Adding a private variable to Animal (to try and differentiate it from the Partial)

   ```js
   class Animal {
     kingdom:string;
     species:string;
     private foo:unknown;

     constructor(config?:Partial<Animal>) {
       this.kingdom = config?.kingdom ?? "";
       this.species = config?.species ?? "";
     }
   }
   ```

   This just changes the error message to:

   ```
   Argument of type 'Animal | Partial<Animal>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Animal'.
     Property 'foo' is missing in type 'Partial<Animal>' but required in type 'Animal'.
   ```
2. An explicit cast:

   ```js
   if (!(animal instanceof Animal)) animal = new Animal(animal) as Animal;
   animals.push(animal);
   ```
3. And even removing the if statement entirely:

   ```js
   animal = new Animal(animal);
   animals.push(animal);
   ```

All of these solutions either have no effect or alter the error message slightly, but the underlying issue remains. TypeScript is not detecting that I've narrowed the type from `Partial<Animal>|Animal` to `Animal`.

The only solution I've found that works so far is an explicit second check:

```js
if (!(animal instanceof Animal)) animal = new Animal(animal);
if ((animal instanceof Animal)) animals.push(animal);
```

This looks very ugly and it feels like it shouldn't be necessary, but I'm willing to accept this (tucked behind a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)) if there is really no other way.

How can I reasonably narrow the type down to just `Animal`, or is this a limitation of TypeScript? An authoritative source would be preferred, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can get TypeScript to narrow that variable when you reuse it in that way. However there are other constructions which will remove the error, here are a few:

---

- Add your manual cast on the `push` line.

This works since this line is where the type mismatch occurs: by assigning a `Animal | Partial<Animal>` to a position expecting only `Animal`.

```
function addAnimal(animal:Animal|Partial<Animal>) {
  if (!(animal instanceof Animal)) animal = new Animal(animal);
  animals.push(animal as Animal);
}
```

---

- Use an inline conversion with a ternary opertator.

TypeScript is smart enough to see that the result of the ternary expression is always of type `Animal`, something it can't do when you reassign to the parameter.

```
function addAnimal(animal:Animal|Partial<Animal>) {
  animals.push(animal instanceof Animal ? animal : new Animal(animal));
}
```

---

- Use a `@ts-ignore` comment.

My goto when TypeScript stops helping me and starts getting in the way. Of course, this ignores any error that may appear; I'd only use it when other workarounds are too onerous.

```
function addAnimal(animal:Animal|Partial<Animal>) {
  if (!(animal instanceof Animal)) animal = new Animal(animal);
  // @ts-ignore: See above line, `animal` is always type `Animal` here.
  animals.push(animal);
}
```

Comment: I've disallowed explicit casting, so the first option will require the third in any case. However, I appreciate the confirmation. I figured this would be the answer, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Comment: Accepting this answer because I basically used a modified version of the second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [CRice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72266376/211627), it seems TypeScript is unable to narrow the *variable*.

The solution I ended up going with was to create a second variable, though it is very similar to CRice's second suggestion.

I renamed the function argument to `animalConfig` and created a new variable named `animal` which is simply typed as `Animal`. Then, I use the ternary operator (again recommended by CRice) with an `instanceof` check to either assign `animalConfig` directly to `animal` if it is an instance of the `Animal` class or I create a new `Animal` instance passing in `animalConfig` as the argument.

```js
const animals:Animal[] = [];
function addAnimal(animalConfig:Animal|Partial<Animal>) {
  const animal = (animalConfig instanceof Animal)
    ? animalConfig
    : new Animal(animalConfig);
  animals.push(animal);
}
```

This avoids `@ts-ignore` (which might hide other errors), explicit casting (which again may hide errors as the code evolves) and multiple type checks (which is inefficient in runtime code).

I still feel like type narrowing should have handled this situation. It is, at least, intuitive, but I guess the technical realities are either too complex or expensive, so this feels like a reasonable compromise.